# Configuring the SSL in Windows Azure

Tags: deployment, ssl, azure

I'm new to Windows azure. I've browsed the web but stuck at the moment. Here is my problem.
I've deployed a web role and uploaded a certificate. I also configured the domain name.

In the control panel certificate name is ***.mydomain.com**. My website responds to **mysubdomain.mydomain.com**. In the properties of my azure project, in certificates tab I added a certificate with name **Mydomain** and copy pased the Thumbprint of my certificate from the control panel.

Then in the Endpoints  tab I added an endpoint

```
   Name: Endpoint2
   Type: Input
   Public port: 8080
   Certificate: Mydomain (the one I recently added)
```

Then I published the project via Visual Studio.

But it doesn't open via https. What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the Issue. I had to change the public port from 8080 to 443 and everything worked fine.